# How to repeat a series of process and calculation for a list of lists?

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, dataframe

I want to calculate a financial index for a list of companies for 20 quarters. For each quarter, the company list is a little bit different, so I have 20 lists to process. However, I'm not quite sure if I need to write a loop or function to iterate the process for all 20 lists?? I've never written any loops before. I'll use 2020-Q1 data for this sample process, so for each quarter, the process should be adjusted to that quarter.

My current codes for one list are as below:

```
> set API key to extract data from financial API

sf.set_api_key('poepcJpfyS4oMRuSEEytWkErpDmdsa0C')

> get company lists of 20 quarter

SPlist = pd.read_csv('Company_List.csv')
```

The SPlist is like below, and I have converted each column into a list so I get 20 lists for all quarters.

```
    3/31/20   12/31/19   9/30/19   6/30/19   3/31/19   12/31/18
0   A         A          A         A         A          A
1   AAL       AAL        AAL       AAL       AAL        AAL 
2   AAP       AAP        AAP       AAP       AAP        AAP 
3   AAPL      AAPL       AAPL      AAPL      AAPL       AAPL    
4   ABBV      ABBV       ABBV      ABBV      ABBV       ABBV
... ...       ...        ...       ...       ...        ... 
500 YUM       YUM        XYL       XYL       XYL        XYL
501 ZBH       ZBH        YUM       YUM       YUM        YUM
502 ZBRA      ZBRA       ZBH       ZBH       ZBH        ZBH
503 ZION      ZION       ZION      ZION      ZION       ZION
504 ZTS       ZTS        ZTS       ZTS       ZTS        ZTS
```

You can find a sample list using the following code, it gets you the list of companies for the most recent quarter.

```
table=pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
df = table[0]
tickers = df.Symbol.to_list()
```

I run the following process for this single list:

```
> Load data from API

sf.set_data_dir('~/simfin_data/')

df = sf.load_income(variant='quarterly', market='us')
dfb = sf.load_balance(variant='quarterly-full', market='us')
dfp = sf.load_shareprices(variant='daily', market='us')

> Only show companies within the ticker list

df_income_qtr = df.loc[tickers]
df_balance_qtr = dfb.loc[tickers]
df_price = dfp.loc[tickers]

> Add NOPAT and Invested Capital in order to get ROIC

df_income_qtr['NOPAT'] = df_income_qtr['Operating Income (Loss)'] - df_income_qtr['Income Tax (Expense) Benefit, Net']
df_balance_qtr['Invested Capital'] = df_balance_qtr['Total Noncurrent Liabilities'] + df_balance_qtr['Total Equity']

> Calculate ROIC

income = df_income_qtr[['Fiscal Year','Publish Date','NOPAT']]
balance = df_balance_qtr[['Invested Capital']]
income2=income.reset_index()
balance2 = balance.reset_index()
combine = pd.merge(income,balance,left_index=True, right_index=True)
combine['ROIC'] = combine['NOPAT']/combine['Invested Capital']

> Get quarterly results by publish date

combine['Publish Date'] = pd.to_datetime(combine['Publish Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
combine['Year_Quarter'] = pd.to_datetime(combine['Publish Date']).dt.to_period('Q').astype(str).str.replace('Q', '-Q')

> Get Q1-2020 ROIC data from the table

Q12020roic = combine[combine['Year_Quarter'] == '2020-Q1']
Q12020roic = Q12020roic[Q12020roic['ROIC'].notnull()]
Q12020roic = Q12020roic.reset_index()

> Get Q1-2020 price data from the table

df_price = df_price.reset_index()
df_price['Market Cap'] = df_price['Adj. Close'] * df_price['Shares Outstanding']
tmp = df_price.groupby(['Ticker', pd.PeriodIndex(df_price['Date'], freq='Q', name='Quarter')]).last().reset_index(level = 0)
individual_df = {str(i): df_price.reset_index(drop=True) for i, df_price in tmp.groupby(['Quarter'])}
Q12020price = individual_df['2020Q1'][['Ticker','Adj. Close','Market Cap']]

> Get a combined table for calculation

Q12020full = Q12020roic.set_index('Ticker').join(Q12020price.set_index('Ticker'))
mktcap = Q12020full['Market Cap'].sum()
Q12020full['Weight'] = Q12020full['Market Cap']/mktcap
qua1, qua2, qua3, qua4, qua5 = np.split(Q12020full[:395].sort_values(by = 'ROIC', ascending = False), 5)
index1 = qua1['Weight'].sum()
index2 = qua2['Weight'].sum()
index3 = qua3['Weight'].sum()
index4 = qua4['Weight'].sum()
index5 = qua5['Weight'].sum()

> This Is the final output I want to get for each quarter:

index1,index2,index3,index4,index5
>(0.33722854216331616,
 0.18763248199902477,
 0.20345912394591914,
 0.13369812569957581,
 0.1317699556564322)
```

This is a complex process and I took some time to go through it just for one quarter. Now I'm struggling in repeating this process for 20 quarters. It might be hard to directly iterate through 20 quarters because you need to change quarters for several variables, but is there any way to simplify some part of this code into a loop or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of the data doesn't change, I'd recommend to wrap the code into functions then use those functions for each one of the companies you must do those tasks. Clearly you must iterate over the pool of companies you wish to calculate their financial index.

I'm taking as an assumption that when you say *"the company list is a little bit different"* we are not talking about structure but length.

Comment: The company lists contain different values and the length is also different. I'm thinking about functions, do you mean I aggregate all the companies in all the lists and iterate through each of them?

Comment: I would like us to be on the same page here, when you say *different values* are just *values*? If we preserve the way they are being stored , for example, using a dictionary o columns in a Dataframe we can still consume the information/values allocated on each of the companies stored in the list. But if the structure changes, for example one company has the key/column "A" and  another one doesn't, we would encounter a normalization issue. 
Our problem isn't the values of the companies, is the structure. If you can abstract a company  metastructure, you can apply functions and solve it.